# For a strongly convex function, does the initialisation of $x_0$ matter?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, newton-raphson

So I am curious what the convergence conditions are for a strongly convex function using the Newton Raphson method. If the function is strongly convex then if the First Order Necessary Conditions hold, then surely we must always be taking steps such that $f_{k+1} < f_k$. This would lead to convergence for an appropriate step size.

Comment: If there are no roots then no root-finding method will converge. Take $x^2+1$ as a simple example.

Comment: Why are you assuming there are no roots? I am also using the NR method to find the local minima